# Java Mail Search : RECENT Flag Doesn't work on GMail

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

```
        Store imapsStore = getStore(imapHost, imapPort, userName, userPass, getProperties(),debugMail);
        Folder givenFolder = imapsStore.getFolder(sourceFolder);
        givenFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        /* Get the messages which is unread in the Inbox */
        Message messages[] = givenFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.RECENT), true));

        /* Use a suitable FetchProfile */
        FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
//      fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
//      fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS);
        givenFolder.fetch(messages, fp);
```

This doesn't return new mails from GMail. ? How To get It Work ? Does It Even Work ?
I know there is SEEN flag as well which is used to mark messages as READ/UNREAD, Im looking for Truly recent messages and not Unread messages.

Comment: @SLaks Yes , RECENT doesn't mean Unread ( which is equivalent to SEEN-> false ) in java Mail. I want recent messages which we never accessed earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gmail doesn't support \Recent.](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78761&topic=1668982&ctx=topic)

Comment: Thanks Bill Shannon ! You are a lifesaver.. :)

Comment: @Rakesh , So, it is not possible to read only recent messages from Gmail??. Or, If you got some solution or workaround then could you please share here.